# Filter-Out function in Scheme

Tags: recursion, filter, functional-programming, scheme, predicate

I need to create a function that filters out predicates in Scheme. For example `(filter-out number? '(a 2 #f b 7))`: the output would be `(a #f b)`

The function that I have returns a list of what was filtered out. How can I change this to get what I need? Thanks

```
(define (filter pred lst)
  (reverse (filter-help pred lst '())))

(define (filter-help pred lst res)
  (cond ((null? lst) res)
        ((pred (car lst)) 
           (filter-help pred (cdr lst)  (cons (car lst) res)))
        (else 
           (filter-help pred (cdr lst)  res))))
```

Comment: typo* sorry. the output should be (a #f b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions work if you just negate the predicate on one line of filter-help (and change the name `filter` to `filter-out` as intended):

```
(not (pred (car lst)))
```

instead of

```
((pred (car lst))
```

Though you could write this more briefly by using the built-in `filter` with a lambda function:

```
(define (alt-filter-out pred lst)
        (filter (lambda (x) (not (pred x))) lst))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `(filter (complement pred) lst)`?